# Easiest way to convert month name to month number in JS ? (Jan = 01)

Tags: javascript, date

Just want to covert **Jan** to **01** (date format)

I can use `array()` but looking for another way...

Any suggestion?

Answer (score 104, accepted):

Just for fun I did this:

```
function getMonthFromString(mon){
   return new Date(Date.parse(mon +" 1, 2012")).getMonth()+1
}
```

Bonus: it also supports full month names :-D
Or the new improved version that simply returns -1 - change it to throw the exception if you want (instead of returning -1):

```
function getMonthFromString(mon){

   var d = Date.parse(mon + "1, 2012");
   if(!isNaN(d)){
      return new Date(d).getMonth() + 1;
   }
   return -1;
 }
```

Sry for all the edits - getting ahead of myself

Comment: Well - keep in mind: I haven't tested it - this was off the cuff.  You might want to try/catch and handle the NaN condition (if the date format was incorrect).  I might update with that.

Comment: @l2aelba Congrats on picking the slowest solution. http://jsperf.com/month-number-speed-test

Comment: @epascarello I'll agree it's slow - just answering OP's question with what he wanted.  Efficiency isn't that big of deal: would I use this when I parse 300+ strings?  Absolutely not!  But if all he's doing is a few runs on each page, then I don't think it matters.

Comment: +1 This may be the slowest, but it's also the only answer on this page that's case-insensitive, locale-safe, has obvious intent, and has a decent failure mode on bad input.

Comment: Yes, all the other answers ignore case and local.

Comment: What's with the +1 in returning the getMonth value?  Seems to throw off date creation by one every time.

Comment: Ha, I finally read this.  getMonth returns a zero index month number (i.e. Jan = 0, Feb = 1).  If it's being thrown off, it's possible you have an override of the getMonth method on the prototype of Date that returns the 'right' month number which would cause a one off.

Comment: correct me if I am wrong but it seems that a comma is missing : `var d = Date.parse(mon +",1, 2012");`

Comment: Check the facts.

`t = Date.now(); for (i=1E6; i; i--) { d = new Date('June 1-0000').getMonth()+1 };     Date.now()-t`

--> 0.56 us/conversion.

`ms = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];`
`t = Date.now(); for (i=1E6; i; i--) { d = ms.indexOf('Jul'.toLowerCase())+1 }; Date.now()-t`

--> 0.49 us/conversion.

Do you really want to use a less flexible JS hack instead of a built-in to save 70 ns?

Answer (score 66):

Another way;

```
alert( "JanFebMarAprMayJunJulAugSepOctNovDec".indexOf("Jun") / 3 + 1 );
```

Comment: You can extend this idea to full month names (3 char names would still work) like this `'January___February__March_____April_____May_______June______July______August____September_October___November__December__'.indexOf("Jun") / 10 + 1`. _Why 10 chars and not 9?_ So if you want to do the reverse, you can trim with `.indexOf('_')`

Comment: Good hack, but I will not use that in production. A map will be simple and extensible too, so that we can map both "Jan" and "January" to 1.

Answer (score 44):

If you don't want an array then how about an object?

```js
const months = {
  Jan: '01',
  Feb: '02',
  Mar: '03',
  Apr: '04',
  May: '05',
  Jun: '06',
  Jul: '07',
  Aug: '08',
  Sep: '09',
  Oct: '10',
  Nov: '11',
  Dec: '12',
}
```

Comment: I agree that using an object (or Array) is more efficient - but the OP asked for non-array.  I know I'll sometimes take the hit on processing time if I can use built in functionality.  Parsing a string into a date is something JS does - so creating a function to utilize it makes sense.

Comment: @AaronRomine Many native methods available in JavaScript are much faster than what you'd achieve re-writing them using JavaScript, and normally I'd make use of them. However, here OP made no indication of wanting anything other than a simple mapping (which happened to involve month names and numbers) and this is the best way I know.

Comment: somehow I still find this one neat. nothing more nothing less and built just for the intended use.

Comment: for key value pair you can have this 
```export const allMonths = {
  'Jan': '01',
  'Feb': '02',
  'Mar': '03',
  'Apr': '04',
  'May': '05',
  'Jun': '06',
  'Jul': '07',
  'Aug': '08',
  'Sep': '09',
  'Oct': '10',
  'Nov': '11',
  'Dec': '12',
}```

Answer (score 22):

One more way to do the same

```
month1 = month1.toLowerCase();
var months = ["jan", "feb", "mar", "apr", "may", "jun", "jul", "aug", "sep", "oct", "nov", "dec"];
month1 = months.indexOf(month1);
```

Comment: Thanks, but you should add 1 to "month1"  in order to get the correct month value. 
function getMonthFromString(mon){
    let month1 = mon.toLowerCase();
    let months = ["janvier", "février", "mars", "avril", "mai", "juin", "juillet", "août", "septembre", "octobre", "novembre", "décembre"];
    return (months.indexOf(month1)+1);
 }

Answer (score 21):

If you are using moment.js:

```
moment().month("Jan").format("M");
```

Comment: Wow works like a charm

Answer (score 11):

I usually used to make a function:

```
function getMonth(monthStr){
    return new Date(monthStr+'-1-01').getMonth()+1
}
```

And call it like :

```
getMonth('Jan');
getMonth('Feb');
getMonth('Dec');
```

Answer (score 9):

For anyone still looking at this answer in 2021, [`toLocaleDateString`](https://caniuse.com/date-tolocaledatestring) now has broad support

```
let monthNumberFromString = (str) => {
  return new Date(`${str} 01 2000`).toLocaleDateString(`en`, {month:`2-digit`})
}
// monthNumberFromString(`jan`) returns 01
```

Answer (score 4):

```
function getMonthDays(MonthYear) {
  var months = [
    'January',
    'February',
    'March',
    'April',
    'May',
    'June',
    'July',
    'August',
    'September',
    'October',
    'November',
    'December'
  ];

  var Value=MonthYear.split(" ");      
  var month = (months.indexOf(Value[0]) + 1);      
  return new Date(Value[1], month, 0).getDate();
}

console.log(getMonthDays("March 2011"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var monthNames = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec'];
```

then just call monthNames[1]
that will be Feb

So you can always make something like

```
  monthNumber = "5";
  jQuery('#element').text(monthNames[monthNumber])
```

Comment: Add parseInt() so we can use "05"

Comment: This seems to be the reverse of what OP wants. "May => 05" and not "05 => May"

Answer (score 2):

Here is a modified version of the chosen answer:

```
getMonth("Feb")
function getMonth(month) {
  d = new Date().toString().split(" ")
  d[1] = month
  d = new Date(d.join(' ')).getMonth()+1
  if(!isNaN(d)) {
    return d
  }
  return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way :

```
var currentMonth = 1
var months = ["ENE", "FEB", "MAR", "APR", "MAY", "JUN", 
              "JUL", "AGO", "SEP", "OCT", "NOV", "DIC"];

console.log(months[currentMonth - 1]);
```

Comment: The post makes complete sense in their chosen language.

Answer (score 1):

```js
function getNumericMonth(monthAbbr) {
      return (String(['January',
        'February',
        'March',
        'April',
        'May',
        'June',
        'July',
        'August',
        'September',
        'October',
        'November',
        'December'].indexOf(monthAbbr) + 1).padStart(2, '0'))
    }
    
   console.log(getNumericMonth('September'));
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple one liner function

```
//ECHMA5
function GetMonth(anyDate) { 
   return 'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(',')[anyDate.getMonth()];
 }
//
// ECMA6
var GetMonth = (anyDate) => 'Jan,Feb,Mar,Apr,May,Jun,Jul,Aug,Sep,Oct,Nov,Dec'.split(',')[anyDate.getMonth()];
```