# count number of object in an array angular js

Tags: angularjs, arrays, object, count

This is what I did.

```
$scope.data.months = [];    
angular.forEach(response, function (value, key) {
      $scope.data.months.push({'month':value});
  });
```

console.log(response) is look like this

```
Array[3]
 0
 :
 "April 2017"
 1
 :
 "May 2017"
 2
 :
 "June 2017"
```

and console.log of months array result is look like this.

```
Array[0]
0 : Object
  month : "April 2017"
__proto__
:
Object
1 : Object
  month : "May 2017"
__proto__
:
Object
2 : Object
  month : "June 2017"
__proto__
:
Object
```

I have two question

-> First one is why it is showing **Array[0]** insist of **Array[3]** as there are three objects in this array.

-> Second one is how to count number of month
I think if first one is solved then second one will be solved from first one.

I am newbie in angular js, What I am doing wrong please guide me through right direction.

Comment: what does array.lengh give you ($scope.data.months.length) at the point you log it?

Comment: Could you tell what is the response ? I hope it is an array.

Comment: yes sure one min

Comment: Also, could you tell where exactly you are writing the console.log

Comment: It is returning 0 @PaulThomasGC

Comment: I am writing it after foreach loop @rohankangale

Comment: Array is having only 1 object and that object is having nested objects...Its showing the right   output

Comment: what should i need to do to get all three object in Array[object,object,object]

Comment: The response most probably is an array(array of objects), containing various objects. So the output is correct.

Comment: @Ramkishan : You need to traverse the array, in order to access the objects. You can do it either using "for" or "angular.forEach" functions.

Comment: ok let me try this

Comment: I am not able to get desired result. even if i console.log($scope.data.months[0]), It is showing undefined.

Comment: Can anybody give me right answer please.

Comment: Please provide the response.

Comment: already provided @MaviDomates

Comment: First, please check the response. You can do that by writing console.log inside the forEach loop. Check the console i.e value.

Comment: I have already provided result of console.log(response) dear @rohankangale

Comment: As i told, write inside the forEach loop. You told that you have written outside the forEach loop.

Comment: result is same in both case @rohankangale

Comment: Which browser is this in?

Comment: google chrome browser

Comment: Can you just try to do something like Object.keys(response).length? That should give you the # of months if they are unique. Are you using a nightly build of chrome? That looks like a bug to me, showing the incorrect number of results in an evaluated array

Comment: It returns 3 in my case

Comment: Another thing is, if you're trying to just collect the names of the months you can use something simpler, I'm guessing there's a reason why you're using a key-value pair while inserting into the array. So just FYI you should be checking the names like months[0].month

Comment: I don't know means of nightly build chrome

Comment: when i use months[0].month it throws error of undefined property of month i don't know why, Totally confused :(

Comment: @Ramkishan you said it returns 3, isn't that what you need?

Comment: response variable is returning 3 but $scope.data.months returns 0 as you have asked me to console.log(Object.keys(response).length).

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your first question. If console show 0 array and opening it show items in it then it is an unresolved promise issue. In other words, when you call your first console.log, the promise is not yet resolved, but resolving it in the meantime will show you the returned array if you open it.

For the second question, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13566552/easiest-way-to-convert-month-name-to-month-number-in-js-jan-01) might help you.