# Optimize my JavaScript Code using Date and Time

Tags: javascript

I would like learn how this code can be done in a more proficient manner.

I am new to JavaScript and I know how to do things but in a simple way I guess.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
var urlstart = "domain.com";
var urlend = "?blah";

var serverTime = "Thu Mar 07 11:23:06 PST 2019";

var st = serverTime.toLowerCase();

var m = st.slice(4,7);

 if ( m === "jan") { 
    var m = "01"
  }
  if (m === "feb") { 
    var m = "02"
  }
  if (m === "mar") { 
    var m = "03"
  }
  if (m === "apr") { 
    var m = "04"
  }
  if (m === "may") { 
    var m = "05"
  }
  if (m === "jun") { 
    var m = "06"
  }
  if (m === "jul") { 
    var m = "07"
  }
  if (m === "aug") { 
    var m = "08"
  }
  if (m === "sep") { 
    var m = "09"
  }
  if (m === "oct") { 
    var m = "10"
  }
  if (m === "nov") { 
    var m = "11"
  }
  if (m === "dec") { 
    var m = "12"
  }

var d = st.slice(8,10);

var y = st.slice(-2);

var t = st.slice(11,23);

var th = t.slice(0,2);
var th = Math.floor(th);

/* 9pm or After */
if (th > 20 ) { 

/* End Of Month - add 1 to Month value and change Day value 1 */
    if ( ( d == "30" && ( m == "04" || m == "06" || m == "09" || m == "11")) || 
    ( d == "31" && ( m == "01" || m == "03" || m == "05" || m == "07" || m == "08" || m == "10")) 
    || ( d == "28" && m == "02") ) {
    var m = Math.floor(m);
    var m = m + 1;
    var m = m.toString();
    var m = m.replace(/\d+/g, function(m){ return "0".substr(m.length - 1) + m; });
    var d = "01";
    window.location.href = urlstart+m+d+y+urlend;
    }

/* End Of the Year - Change M and Day and Year */
    else if ( m =="12" && d=="31" ) {
    var m = "01";
    var d = "01";
    var y = Math.floor(y);
    var y = y + 1;
    var y = y.toString();
    var y = y.replace(/\d+/g, function(y){ return "0".substr(y.length - 1) + y; });
    window.location.href = urlstart+m+d+y+urlend;
    }

else { /* Days that are not End Of Month */
var d = Math.floor(d);
var d = d + 1;
var d = d.toString();
var d = d.replace(/\d+/g, function(d){ return "0".substr(d.length - 1) + d; });

window.location.href = urlstart+m+d+y+urlend;

}

} else {

window.location.href = urlstart+m+d+y+urlend;

}
```

Thank you for your time.
................................................................................................................................................

Comment: What is this code trying to _do_ that you want to optimize? What is the initial value of `serverTime`?

Comment: There exist several date/time parsing libraries, you could use one of those, then you just may need to specify the format as something like `dd MMM yyyy` and you will get an object that has all relevant parts as properties.

Comment: sorry! updated with serverTime var

Comment: Ok so you mean pulling something like an end of the month variable using a library instead of manually doing it? @H.B.

Comment: @Buildingbrick: You usually provide a format string, that specifies where which parts are and how they are written, e.g. `yyyy` would be 4 digit year, and the object you get back then has a property, maybe called `year`, that provides that part as a number. Then you can work with that object. If you need something like the end of the month, libraries sometimes provide utility functions that can help with such queries as well.

Comment: You can change all `if()` to `else if()` because if you use `if()` all conditions will be check but for `else if()` just 1 or runs until a true condition is met. An other better code is [in here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13566552/4229270) You can check that too. You can also optimise code by using [JS Date functions](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp). No need to slice from the string for month, date, time etc...